# running tally in SQL

Tags: sql, join, sum

Need help tallying fork truck training completions at work.  Here is an example of the tables I have, and the table I need to create:

table 1:

| date | is_work_day |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-25 | 1 |
| 2023-01-26 | 1 |
| 2023-01-27 | 1 |
| 2023-01-28 | 0 |
| 2023-01-29 | 1 |
| 2023-01-30 | 0 |

table 2:

| employee_id | training_passed | test_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 2023-01-25 |
| 002 | 1 | 2023-01-26 |
| 003 | 0 | 2023-01-26 |
| 004 | 1 | 2023-01-26 |
| 005 | 0 | 2023-01-27 |
| 006 | 1 | 2023-01-29 |

need table:

| date | cumulative_passed_training |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-26 | 2 |
| 2023-01-27 | 2 |
| 2023-01-29 | 3 |

The table should count the total passed trainings, but only starting on 2023-01-26 and should only show dates that are work days.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I think I need to JOIN the two tables, and then SUM the training_passed column, but am unsure how to get it to start at a certain date, and how to make it only show work days on the final table.

Answer (score 1):

JOIN on the date column and add the passed tests as JOIN condition. Also GROUP BY the date so you can sum for each one

```
select t1.date, count(t2.employee_id)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1. date = t2.test_date 
              and t2.training_passed = 1
group by t1.date
```

It would make no difference if you put the condition

```
t2.training_passed = 1
```

in a `where` clause instead of the INNER JOIN.

Comment: "1/25/2023" "1"
"1/26/2023" "6"
"1/29/2023" "6"
That's the table I got.  Not sure what it's adding..

Comment: It should be       select t1.date, sum(t2.training_passed)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1. date = t2.test_date 
              and t2.training_passed = 1
group by t1.date

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to move down without hitting enter, so I have to put multiple comments.  Sorry.  Anyway, It should be training_passed in that first line.  That still doesn't get me to the table I need though.  I need a running total of trainings passed as each day goes on, not a total number of trainings passed for individual days.

Comment: My mistake. Use `count()` instead of `sum()` of course.

Comment: Hmm, still no running tally.  Gives me the same result as sum.

Comment: select t1.date, sum(t2.training_passed) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS cumulative_training_passed
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1. date = t2.test_date 
              and t2.training_passed = 1
group by t1.date

Comment: That seemed to work.  Thanks for the help!